Why can't I get supervisor recognize new .conf files in Laravel Sail/Docker installation?
so I've got a scout-worker.conf in /etc/supervisor/conf.d It contains this code:
[program:scout-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=docker exec cercasemi-laravel.test-1 php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work redis --queue=scout --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/scout-worker.log

But when I issue a command like this, it doesn't recognize the new scout-worker.conf:
docker exec cercasemi-laravel.test-1 supervisorctl reread
it answers:
No config updates to processes
Why?
